# Calculo de cantidad de cuotas a vencer según el mes actual

Tags: python-3.x

Soy un entusiasta y he creado una rutina que me calcula la cantidad de cuotas a pagar según el mes en el que se carga el servicio.
Cada servicio puede tener 12,6, 4, 3, 2 o 1 cuota. dependiendo del servicio.
Si el día de caga del servicio es mayor a 20 esa cuota no se generará y se descontará a la cantidad de cuotas

La rutina funciona pero no es para nada elegante.

Cómo podría mejorarla??

agradeceré sus sugerencias.-

```
now = datetime.now()
def canCuotas(cuotas):
    if now.month == 1:
        if cuotas == 12:
            if now.day >20:
                return (cuotas -1) 
        else:
            return cuotas
    elif now.month == 2:
        if cuotas == 12:
            if now.day > 20:
                return (cuotas - 2)
            else:
                return (cuotas - 1) 
        elif cuotas == 6:
            if now.day > 20:
                return (cuotas -1)
            else:
                return cuotas
        else:
            return cuotas
    elif now.month == 3:
        if cuotas == 12:
            if now.day > 20:
                return (cuotas - 3)
            else:
                return (cuotas - 2)
        elif cuotas == 6:
                return (cuotas -1)
        elif cuotas == 4:
            if now.day > 20:
                return (cuotas -1)
            else:
                return cuotas
        else:
            return cuotas
    if now.month == 4:
        if cuotas == 12:
            if now.day > 20:
                return (cuotas - 4)
            else:
                return (cuotas - 3)
        elif cuotas == 6:
                if now.day > 20:
                return (cuotas - 2)
            else:
                return (cuotas - 1)
        elif cuotas == 4:
                return (cuotas -1)
        elif cuotas == 3:
            if now.day > 20:
                return (cuotas - 1)
            else:
                return cuotas 
        else:
            return cuotas
    elif now.month == 5:
        if cuotas == 12:
            if now.day>20:
                return (cuotas- 5)
            else:
                return (cuotas - 4)
        elif cuotas == 6:
            return (cuotas - 2)
        elif cuotas == 4:
            return (cuotas -1)
        elif cuotas == 3:
            return (cuotas - 1)
        else:
            return cuotas
    elif now.month == 6:
        if cuotas == 12:
            if now.day > 20:
                return (cuotas - 6)
            else:
                return (cuotas - 5)
        elif cuotas == 6:
            if now.day > 20:
                return (cuotas - 3)
            else:
                return (cuotas - 2)
        elif cuotas == 4:
            if now.day > 20:
                return (cuotas - 2)
            else:
                return (cuotas - 1)
        elif cuotas == 3:
            return cuotas - 1
        elif cuotas == 2:
            if now.day > 20:
                return (cuotas -1)
            else:
                return cuotas
        else:
            return cuotas
```

y así sigue preguntando por cada mes.

lo cual lo hace extremadamente largo y difícil de mantener

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español, mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funciona el sitio y de paso obtener tu primera medalla. Normalmente las preguntas que se basan en opiniones terminan cerradas, sería mejor si tu pregunta fuese más puntual respecto a lo que quieres obtener. Saludos.

Comment: Hay unos `if/elif` que tiene otra validación adentro, puedes optimizarlo usando el operador `and` para validar las tres condiciones de una sola vez.